# How many different messages can be transmitted in n microseconds using three different signals...

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> **How many different messages can be transmitted in n microseconds using three different signals if one signal requires 1 microsecond for transmittal, the other two signals require 2 microseconds each for transmittal, and a signal in a message is followed immediately by the next signal?**

I initially got it wrong because I put as the initial condition: $a_0=0, \space a_1=1$

I found this solution online:

> [image]

Why is the initial condition $a_2=3$, and not $a_2=2$?  It says the other two signals require $2$ microseconds, so I believe $a_2=2$ because in $2$ microseconds we can only send $2$ signals.

Comment: If "A" takes $1$ microsecond and "B" and "C" take $2$, then in $2$ microseconds you can send any of the following: "AA", "B", or "C".

Comment: You can also start at $0$ by noting there's exactly one message you can send in $0$ microseconds, namely the empty message (no signal). Then the recursion naturally gives you $a_2=a_1+2a_0=1+2\cdot 1=3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting a comment from mjqxxxx to a CW answer

If "A" takes 1 microsecond and "B" and "C" take 2, then in 2 microseconds you can send any of the following: "AA", "B", or "C".

Answer (score 0):

i found a online solution in which it is showing An = An-1+An-2 because we have two choise here either we can send first signal which 1 second time or we can send another signal which takes two second time anyone of them we can send first so i think the value of A1 = 1 because in 1st second we can send  a signal which takes 1 second time and A2 = 1 because in 2 second we cannot send two signal which takes 1 second it is cleared by question so in two second we can send only one signal which takes two second.

Comment: It is possible to post mathematical notation, including subscripts and superscripts, using $\LaTeX$ syntax with `MathJax`.  See [this short introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and its links to more detailed information.